# Unable to send images on UDP larger than 10K

Tags: c#, udp

I am trying to develop a client/server application in which client will send images to the server.

### Case 1:

Server is running on one machine that is behind a router and client is running on another machine that is behind some different router. As this communication will be on WAN (public IPs), a port is forwarded on server side router so that server can easily receive incoming UDP datagrams on that port.

UDP's maximum transmission unit (MTU) size is 64KB. It means a UDP socket should be able to transmit anything thing of size less than or equal to 65,536 bytes. When in case of the application i am developing the client is only able to send an image(UDP datagram) of 10-13k. If i try to transfer an image of the size greater than 10Kb, server is unable to receive it and server side UDP socket will be always in (receive) blocking mode.

### Case 2:

Server is running on a machine that is behind a router and client is running on a machine that is behind the same router. It means client & server are on the same local area network. Even client and server are sharing the same local area network client is sending the images (UDP datagrams) on server's public IP. In this case server is able to receive any size of UDP datagram upto 64K, which is what i am expecting from my application.

I tried to run my client on different remote PCs but the result is same. Server is not able to receive a UDP datagram of bigger than 10-13Kb. If anyone can help me to deal with this situation, he would be much appreciated.

Link to the code: 
http://pastebin.com/f644fee71

Thanks and goodluck with your projects.
Regards,

Atif

Comment: Why are you using UDP instead of TCP?

Answer (score 12):

Although the IP layer may allow UDP packets of up to 64k in size I think you will find that the maximum "in the wild" UDP packet size will be limited to the smallest MTU of the devices in between your source and destination.

The standard Ethernet MTU is ~1500 bytes.  Some devices support "jumbo" frames of up to ~10kbytes to improve performance.  But this sort of thing isn't generally supported over the public internet, only on LANs.

The IP layer may fragment the UDP packet (unless the no-fragment bit is set in the packet).  But the recipient will only receive and defragment the packet if every fragment is received in order (or out of order within a specific time limit).  Otherwise it will discard the packet.

It may also be the case that not all the devices in between your source and destination support the frame size of the sending device.  I've encountered situations where I needed to lower the MTU on my routers to ~1450 bytes because intermediate routers were discarding packets at 1500.  This is due to MTU discovery not working reliably.  Ie, the sending device has no way of determinging what the MTU is of devices on its path to the destination.  Somewhere in that path a device will be discarding packets it considers too large.

UDP is a very bad idea for what you are doing.  You would be better off using TCP.

If you are concerned about the performance of TCP connection setup/tear down then keep the connection up for as long as possible.

UDP is only a good protocol for delivering data when you don't care too much about whether the target receives the packet or not.  Delivery is not guaranteed.  In all other cases use TCP.

If you are determined to use UDP you will have to implement [path MTU discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_discovery) in your protocol and prey that the routers/firewalls don't block the "fragmentation needed" ICMP packets.  Which they shouldn't otherwise TCP wouldn't work either.  But like I said, I've seen cases in the past where fragmentation needed ICMP packets are blocked or discarded and I had to manually tweak my own MTU.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a unreliable datagram protocol.  The packets are not guaranteed to arrive at their destination, or in the order that you sent them either.

In addition, when sending packets larger than around 1500 bytes you'll find they get fragmented, or worse, dropped.   The receiver will try to piece it together best it can.
But if anything is missing, goodbye packet.  So really, the limit is actually around that 1500 byte mark but sometimes much less to ensure no fragmentation and that they arrive.  To send data larger than that a higher level protocol is going to have to put them all back together for you and request anything thats missing.

How big will the images be?  64K might be too small anyway.

You have two or three options.

1) Use TCP - it's reliable and stream orientated.  You don't have to worry about how big or small or fragmentation as this is taken care of for you.

2) Use UDP but develop a higher level application protocol on top. Depending on your protocol that could be quite a bit of work.  I'm doing this right now though.

3) Have a look at using the UDT library.  It's designed for transferring bulk data over a WAN and has better performance than TCP.

However, I would like to suggest that TCP will likely suit your needs just fine.